# Socket.IO - how to handle Node.js offline

Tags: node.js, sockets, callback

Everything works great with different browsers connected to the same port chatting away, but when I close my Node server with ctrl+C, I get the following error in my browser:

```
GET http://my-url net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

I've tried the following client-side callbacks:

```
socket.on('reconnect_attempt' ...
socket.on('message' ...
```

But they don't trigger, so I did a dirty hack which does work; using a timer to check the socket every second and if the node server goes down, then do a redirect:

```
setInterval(function(){ 
  if (socket.disconnected) window.open("http://otherurl","_self"); 
}, 1000);
```

Is there a better way to detect if a node server goes offline using client-side js code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per this other SO question [How can I detect disconnects on socket.io?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20007453/how-can-i-detect-disconnects-on-socket-io)

**Below is copied for quick reference:**

socket.io has a disconnect event, put this inside your connect block:

```
socket.on('disconnect', function () {
    //do stuff
});
```

Comment: Sorry for the belated acceptance of answer; your code works and negates my timer solution posted in the OP.

Answer (score 0):

I've found it! You just need to listen for error event (socket.io 0.9)

```
socket.on('error', function() {
      // handle server error here
      console.log('Error net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED occured. Handle me');
});
```

This event was not documented in socket.io client 0.9 docs, which was strange