# How can I check socket.io connect or disconnect on android?

Tags: android, node.js, websocket, socket.io

I connect to the node server with socketio.SocketIO running as a service.And, When Service restarts,opens socket.io without socket.io closure.That's a problem.
A device making multiple socketIO connection on the server side.So the server is swelling..

! I am using gottox/socketio-java-client on android.

Answer (score 2):

Check Socket is connected or not using `socket.isConnected()`.
This will return true if socket is connected

Answer (score 1):

You can check the socket.connected property:

```
var socket = io.connect();

console.log('Connected status before onConnect', socket.socket.connected);

socket.on('connect', function() {
  console.log('Connected status onConnect', socket.socket.connected);
});
```

It's updated dynamically, if the connection is lost it'll be set to false until the client picks up the connection again. So easy to check for with setInterval or something like that.

Another solution would be to catch disconnect events and track the status yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Its just an idea so i don't know the limitations. pls let me know.

You can ping the server to check if the connection is alive.

In android

```
socket.emit("ping","ping");
socket.on("pong",pingHandler); //EmitterListener

private Emitter.Listener pingHandler=new Emitter.Listener(){
 @Override
        public void call(final Object... args) {
            Log.d("SocketStatus","Connection is active");
           });
}
```

and make the server return response for the ping

```
socket.on("ping",function(data){
socket.emit("pong","pong"); //from your server ex.Node.js
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The following is an expansion/modification of Rafique Mohammed answer above.  The correct way is to try to reconnect on client side.

**Internet drops** (server cannot communicate disconnection to client). **Server crashes** (server may/may not be able to tell client. **Server Restart** (server can tell but that just extra work).  **After reconnection** you will also  like to **rejoin the room** for seamless communication

```
public void connectAfterDisconnectSocket(String senderActivity) {

    new Timer().scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            boolean isConnected = false;
            isConnected = mSocket != null && mSocket.connected();

            if (!isConnected) {

                SocketIOClient socketIOClient = new SocketIOClient();
                socketIOClient.connectToSocketIO();

                if (senderActivity.equals("A")) {
                    A.joinChatRoom(room);
                }

                if (senderActivity.equals("B")) {
                    B.joinChatRoom(room);
                }
            }
        }
    }, 0, 1000); //put here time 1000 milliseconds=1 second
}
```